# How to respond to SMS from AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

When I receive an SMS from a friend's mobile phone, I can respond to it (as you would expect).  When I receive an SMS from my application, via AWS SNS, I can not respond.  Why is that?  And can I configure a response phone number?

Answer (score 3):

There is no in-bound SMS capability with Amazon Simple Notification Service. It is only for outbound messaging.

However, [Amazon Pinpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/) can respond to SMS messages, typically as part of a marketing campaign.

See: [Amazon Pinpoint Launches Two-Way Text Messaging | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-pinpoint-launches-two-way-text-messaging/)